# Print the changes I have made in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with cells to be filled by individuals.  When changes are made in the cells, and the print formula is used, and the changes are printed, however when I make a copy of the sheet, the formula does not work for the new sheet.  How/what do I need to add to this formula so when a copy is made, it prints with the changes made in the new copy.

=LET(sheet_id, "1aLp8dm0SVro7NfxzhTblcUq3T8wtf9ViVkBP4wgQ8DI", HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&sheet_id&"/export?format=pdf&size=LETTER&fzr=false&fzc=false&portrait=false&scale=2&top_margin=0.75&bottom_margin=0.75&left_margin=0.25&right_margin=0.25&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid=1797144588&range=A1:L59", "PRINT"))

Comment: `When changes are made in the cells, and the print formula is used, the changes are not in the printed file.` I've tried your formula and it works. There is a syntax error: `> "PRINT"))` should be `"PRINT"))` but that is all. Please provide a [minimal, workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the specific problem that you are experiencing.

Comment: Here is the working example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KFw3P6G-CyexNoywmMi6g10hrHd_C7_27gM_I-2jSM/edit?usp=sharing.  When printing, the cells that are changed (the dropdowns) do not show up printed...they are blank.

Comment: The sheet_ID used in the formula is pointing to a totally different sheet which is causing this amiss. fixed now.

Comment: also, is it possible to have this formula translate when a copy of this is made?

Comment: @BrianRuehle: Changes to your question, can be made using [edit] (as long as your question is **not** answered!), and should not be done my making additional requested in the comments.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow the formula below works: =LET(sheet_id, "1aLp8dm0SVro7NfxzhTblcUq3T8wtf9ViVkBP4wgQ8DI", HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&sheet_id&"/export?format=pdf&size=LETTER&fzr=false&fzc=false&portrait=false&scale=2&top_margin=0.75&bottom_margin=0.75&left_margin=0.25&right_margin=0.25&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid=1797144588&range=A1:L59", "PRINT"))     but i need to be able to make a copy of the sheet and have the formula work for the new page.  How can this happen?

Comment: Well the `only way` I know of is  to **manually** update this new sheet_id within the formula when you take a copy.